# How to learn proper Japanese handwriting

Tags: handwriting

I know the stroke order of kanji and the kana, I can write them. But Japanese handwriting is a lot different from our templates or RTK kanji. They look different (like the special "そ"), but also with kanji I see people sometimes not finishing certain strokes, or the whole kanji is different.
How can you learn these things? All the recources online only give the "textbook" writing, or font writing. And if I look for handwriting fonts they still give really neat writing, instead of the native, faster, hand. I want to look more professional with my handwriting, but professionals don't have a handwriting that's a replica of the standard writings, but a kind of different stylistic feel.
My question is: how do you learn this?

Comment: For me as a Chinese, I was told to write exactly like the "templates" at a very young age. But as I grew older I started to take "shortcuts", like writing 口 with just one stroke. They kind of just come naturally. And that's  when it started to looked like natural handwriting.

Comment: there is also Japanese (and Chinese I assume) calligraphy. Calligraphy is even more fluid and loose than "natural handwriting"... But calligraphy can be taught, and you might find online resources or local instructors for it. Otherwise, as @Sweeper says, you might just have to develop your own style over years of writing. All Japanese children start with the precise version, in school though. So studying the precision-written form is important.

Comment: Look for ペン字 *Penji* workbooks. You can probably follow them well enough even if you're a  Japanese beginner.  Also, if you own a Nintendo DS, buy *DS Bimoji Training*, it's worth it.

Comment: In addition to what was already given, my advice is to get yourself a grade school calligraphy textbook and workbook. Japanese kids are taught the proper ways of writing (harai, tome, hane, etc.) from grade school. Also, don't worry too much about trying to write like a native (fast, fluid). With much practice and experience, you'll eventually write like them. Good luck!